# How to get array output without using pointers in this C program example?

Tags: c, arrays

Here is the C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{
    int i,n;
    char a[100];

    printf("Enter number of teams");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nenter team %d",i);
        scanf("%s",a);
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",a[i]);
    }
}
```

My program is simple, but its crashing. i just want to load in a few names into array and then print them back. I am able to do that but at last line, its crashing.

Comment: `printf("%s", a[i]);` is wrong because type of `a[i]` is `char`, you must enable compiler warnings.

Comment: array index start from 0 and goes till n-1. and what are you expecting with `scanf("%s",a);` in a loop?

Comment: Also, arrays are indexed from 0, not 1.

Comment: You have some serious misunderstandings of very basic stuff. You should read a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to get that sorted out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP doesn't have basic understanding of strings/arrays in C

Comment: @POW which is why the OP asked this question.

Comment: @downvoters(whoever they maybe, I am not addressing any particular person, I am just saying in general) .My account has been banned from asking questions and the stackoverflow has asked me to review my questions. I don't see how this question is wrong by any means. So if there is any improvement, please suggest so, or else please consider upvoting this question, so I get back my ability to ask questions on this site. I like stackoverflow and would like to be part of this community, so I want your help either in terms of suggestions for re-formatting the question or in form of upvotes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code

1. `main()` must return `int`
2. `a` should be an array of strings, and it's an array of `char`, you can do it with an array of `char` arrays, declare it as

   ```
   char a[100][100];
   ```
3. Arrays in c are indexed from `0` to `n - 1` and not from `1` to `n`.
4. You must check if the first `scanf()` worked, furthermore, you must check that `n` is not too big so this part does that

   ```
   if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
       return 1;
   if (n > 100)
       n = 100;
   ```
5. You should prevent a buffer overflow, for that you can use the length specifier for `scanf()`, if your array can store 100 `char`'s then you need to use

   ```
   scanf("%99s", a[i]);
   ```

   because you also need the terminating `'\0'`.
6. Your `printf()` statement is using the wrong specifier, because you are passing a `char` and the `"%s"` is specting a c string.

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    int i, n;
    char a[100][100];

    printf("Enter number of teams");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;
    if (n > 100)
        n = 100;

    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        printf("\nenter team %d",i);
        scanf("%99s", a[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

also, even though you are not explicitly manipulating pointers, you can't avoid that completely, because for example `printf()` takes a pointer parameter for the `"%s"` specifier, it's just that in this case you don't explicitly pass a pointer, but the `i-th` array of the array of `char` arrays will automatically decay to a pointer in

```
printf("%s", a[i]);
```

Comment: Minor: Consider stating the most important issues first (#2 & #3). Also use differ sizes in array rather than 100,100, maybe `char a[20][50];` or `#define M,N`.  It helps in understanding code like `if (n > 20) ....       scanf("%49s", a[i]);`

Answer (score 3):

A `char[]` is equivalent to a string in C when it is terminated with a NUL character (`\0`). You need to create a `char[][]`, or an array of `char[]`s.

So, an *array of strings* in C can be defined as:

```
char arr[5][100];
//The 5 is the number of strings, and 100 is the length of a single string.
```

Also, in C, array indexing starts from `0`, not `1`.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,n;
    printf("Enter number of teams");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char a[n][100];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nenter team %d",i);
        scanf("%s",a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `char arr[5][100]` is not an array of strings, it's an array of `char` arrays, for the contents to be strings, they must be `'\0'` terminated. And though it's not harmful, c++ is not relevant to this question.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add that. Thanks. @iharob the OP tagged it with `c++` before.

Comment: Can be defined makes it a much better post.